# Create Lazy Spark Read-Write Parquet Job in R using Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparkr, sparklyr

I would like to create a spark job which reads from a sql source (using 'spark_read_jdbc') and then writes the results to a parquet file ('spark_write_parquet').

This operation needs to be performed multiple times over for small increments in the sql statement. I would like the job to be created lazily so that multiple executors can pick up the job. Here is some example toy code:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_%s"
for(i in seq(1,10)){
  sql_to_read = sprintf(sql, i)
  optionSet$dbtable = paste0("(", sql_to_read ,") foo")
  TEMP = spark_read_jdbc(sc, "TEMP", options = optionSet, memory = FALSE)
  TEMP = TEMP %>% mutate(id := i)
  TEMP %>% spark_write_parquet(., path = "/TEMP.parquet", mode = "append", partition_by = id)
}
```

The problem is that the write operation cannot be executed lazily forcing a serial operation. Is there a way to write this code so that a spark job is simply created for the full operation, and then when I kick of a 'collect' statement multiple executors will perform the operation?

Comment: A similar problem was solved in scala using threads: https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/how-to-use-threads-in-spark-job-to-achieve-parallel-read-and-writes/

Comment: Why won't you use external orchestration? This looks like something that could be done with Airflow for example, just by passing parameters array. That being said, to be able to submit multiple jobs at the time you'd need threading, and R doesn't have native multi-threading. It should be perfectly possible to delegate it to JVM, but it looks like to much trouble to be honest. You could also build a new connection for each job in a separate process.

Comment: It would be preferable to keep everything in a single environment. The purpose of spark is to distribute processing (either across local executors or a cluster of machines), and is thus a parallel architecture by design. The prize would be to create lazy spark_write_parquet jobs, and then once the full job is designed hand it over to spark to execute.

Comment: There is no conflict here. Simple Spark migrations like this can be easily handled with single operator and almost no code. Anyway, I guess the message here is - you can do it, but implementing behavior like this will require delegating at least part of the processing outside single threaded R environment. Doing this the right way, especially handling partial failures, would require quite a lot of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use the structure of your code to avoid the problem completely. Because all writes use the same output table you can define the input as a single union:

```
xs <- 1:10
query <- glue::glue("SELECT {xs} AS _id, * FROM TBL_{xs}") %>% 
  glue::collapse(" UNION ALL \n")
```

and then

```
optionSet$dbtable <- glue::glue("({query}) tmp")

spark_read_jdbc(sc, "TEMP", options = optionSet, memory = FALSE) %>%
  spark_write_parquet(., path = "/TEMP.parquet", mode = "append", partition_by = id)
```

You can also use `id` as a `partitionColumn` and `min(xs)` / `max(xs)` as `lowerBound` / `upperBound` to [parallelize reads](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/05_spark_sql_and_dataset_api.md#parallelizing-reads).

Comment: Not what I was expecting, but deserves a reward for a nice catch.